# Kong throws no Route matched with those values

Tags: kubernetes, kong

I'm trying to setup Kong in Kubernetes. While following the official documentation from https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller/2.6.x/guides/using-kongingress-resource/ I'm, unable to make it work.
Every request I make to the URL it ends up with no route.

```
curl -X GET  https://<$PROXY_IP>/<service_name>  -L
{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}%
```

Kong logs don't throw any errors and I can see the route and service in Kong admin.
My k8s objects are the following

```
    Ingress Config:
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        konghq.com/override: <service_name>
        meta.helm.sh/release-name: <service_name>
        meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: services
      creationTimestamp: "2022-09-23T14:03:05Z"
      generation: 1
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
      name: <service_name>
      namespace: <service_ns>
      resourceVersion: "18823478"
      uid: 10f15c94-0c56-4d27-b97d-0ad5bdd549ec
    spec:
      ingressClassName: kong
      rules:
      - http:
          paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: <service_name>
                port:
                  number: 8080
            path: /<service_name>
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    status:
      loadBalancer:
        ingress:
        - ip: 172.16.44.236
```

```
apiVersion: configuration.konghq.com/v1
kind: KongIngress
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: <service_name>
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: services
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-23T14:03:05Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  name: <service_name>
  namespace: services
  resourceVersion: "18823487"
  uid: 9dd47a3c-598a-48fe-ba60-29779156b58d
route:
  methods:
  - GET
  strip_path: true
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    konghq.com/override: <service_name>
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: <service_name>
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: services
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-23T14:03:04Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: <service_name>
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: <service_name>
    app.kubernetes.io/version: latest
    helm.sh/chart: <local_chart>
  name: authenticate
  namespace: services
  resourceVersion: "18820083"
  uid: a3112c22-4df7-40b0-8fd3-cde8516354cc
spec:
  clusterIP: 172.16.45.71
  clusterIPs:
  - 172.16.45.71
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: <service_name>
    app.kubernetes.io/name: <service_name>
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I'm battling this issue for days now and I can't seem to figure it out.